# Reading and projecting ESRI grid adf in R

Tags: r, spatial, raster, esri

I am having trouble working with a DEM file in R that is available as an ESRI grid adf file (e.g. a folder with various adf files such as hdr.adf, w001001.adf etc.)

I can use the raster package to read and plot the file:

```
dem<-raster("w001001.adf")
plot(dem)
```

The resulting plot looks fine and I can do things like crop the file. However, I want to reproject the file from:

```
 +proj=laea +lat_0=-100 +lon_0=6370997 +x_0=45 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

To:

```
 +proj=aea +lat_1=49.0628 +lat_2=50.4997 +lon_0=-113.5986 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0
```

based on another raster. The two rasters have different extents and resolutions in addition to projections and I usually use the `spatial_sync_raster` from the `spatial.tools` R package to deal with this type of conversion. But the result is an empty raster. I can't figure out if this is because I haven't properly read in the ESRI adf data (i.e. it's all in memory) or because the spatial sync is too complicated. I've tried just cropping the dem layer to an approximate extent consistent with the second raster and using the `projectRaster` command from the `raster` package (so removing the resolution issue and just trying a straight up projection), but again get an empty raster. SO I think the issue is with importing the adf file. Several days of googling has revealed no R-only solutions (I'd rather not have to invoke ArcGIS).

I appreciate any and all help!

Bits of code tried is:

```
dem_p<-projectRaster(dem,crs=target_proj)
dem_p<-spatial_sync_raster(dem,climate,method="bilinear")
```

Comment: I would like to help but can't with out some data. Can you share the file or make an example raster that has the same issue

Comment: I had a similar issue with landcover data from Landfire. link below 
It seems to be delivered in the arcGrid file format and I hit a dead-end in finding out how to read that into R 

[CONUS 2014 Veg layer](https://www.landfire.gov/bulk/downloadfile.php?FNAME=US_105_mosaic_Refresh-US_105_ESP.zip&TYPE=landfire)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the raster layer is correctly loaded, you can match the resolution of one raster to another using `resample()` from {raster}, then reproject the new raster with `project()` from {terra}

```
pacman::p_load(raster,terra,dplyr)

# resample ras resolution
dem1 <- dem1 %>% resample(dem2) 

# change projection
dem1 %>% project("+proj=aea +lat_1=49.0628 +lat_2=50.4997 +lon_0=-113.5986 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0")
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to do

```
library(terra)
dem <- rast("w001001.adf")
p <- project(dem, "+proj=aea +lat_1=49.0628 +lat_2=50.4997 +lon_0=-113.5986 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m")
```

It is generally better, however, to provide a raster template as second argument. In that way you also control the output extent and resolution.